# How to generate functioning Ruby client from Thrift IDL with circular reference?

Tags: ruby, thrift, idl

My Thrift IDL has a circular reference but has no problem functioning in Java (both as a server and client). The generated code won't work in Ruby, though we've found it will work if each class is broken into a separate file & required in others. I thought about mimicking this file structure in the Thrift IDL but (in addition to being much less organized) it fails because the Thrift compiler is pretty naive about resolution itself (I believe it follows the includes back & forth, stuck in an infinite loop at compile time).

Is there a way to resolve this other than manually editing/post-processing the generated Ruby client?

I found a Jira ticket requesting support for this but its so old it must have been forgotten. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-476

(I also know they recently added a compiler option for namespacing but I don't think that would help alleviate this? I'm not a big Ruby-ist... https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-2574)

The IDL is similar to this though we are converting to "union" for the container... if you have a better solution for polymorphism would love to hear that as well. :)

```
struct Collection {
  1: list<CollectionElement> collection_elements;
}

struct CollectionElement {
   1: PolymorphContainer x;
   2: i32 quantity;
}

struct PolymorphContainer {
    1: Type1 x;
    2: Type2 y;
    3: Collection z;
}
```

Comment: Since you seem to have a test case, please file a ticket.